# Proving the limits using epsilon-delta

Tags: limits

Prove that if $\lim_{x \to c}f(x)=L$ and $\lim_{x \to c}g(x)=\infty$ then $$\lim_{x \to c}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$$
If we fix  an $\epsilon_1$ then we can find a $\delta_1$ such that $|x-c|<\delta_1 \implies |f(x)-L|<\epsilon_1 \implies L-\epsilon_1<f(x)<L+\epsilon_1 \implies |f(x)|< max (|L+\epsilon_1|, |L-\epsilon_1|)=\epsilon'$ So we get for $|x-c|<\delta_1$ we have $$|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}|<\frac{\epsilon'}{|g(x)|}$$ Now if we choose any $\epsilon$ and want to keep $$|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}|<\epsilon$$ then we have to make $\frac{\epsilon_1}{|g(x)|}<\epsilon$ and for that $|g(x)|>\frac{\epsilon_1}{\epsilon}$ and this Inequalitiy is true for $x$ sufficiently close to $c$ as $\lim_{x \to c}g(x)=\infty$
Is My Proof Correct???

Answer (score 1):

The idea is correct but for a neat proof do  the following. Fix any $\epsilon_1$. You can toke this to be $1$. This will give you a  $\delta_1$. Then there exits $\delta_2$ such that $|g(x)| >\frac  1{\epsilon} $ for $|x-c| <\delta_2$. Now take $\delta$ to be the minimum of $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$.